# GET form will not echo

Tags: php, html

I'm starting to learn PHP and keep getting stuck at this point after copying word for word on each guide I'm following. When I complete the form below it updates the query string but dose not echo out the paragraph, same for print. Other answers I've seen for this say to reinstall the server but I have it on Host Gator.

```
<form methon="get" action="index.php">

<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit" name="name" value="submit">

</form>


    <?php

        $name = $GET_['name'];
        $age = $GET_['age'];

        echo '<p>' . $name '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $age . '</p>';



     ?>
```

Comment: `methon`? what?..

Comment: this `$GET_[...]` should be `$_GET[...]` on the form `method`, not `methon`

Comment: you have typo error should use method not methon

Comment: 1. `methon` should be `method` 2. `$GET_['name']` should be `$_GET['...']` 3. echo '<p>' . $name . '</p>'; you forgot the 2nd dot

Comment: It's $_GET.  If you learn php - please learn it carefully

Comment: 3. `echo '<p>' . $name '</p>';` should be `echo '<p>' . $name. '</p>';`

Comment: From where are you learning PHP by the way..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        $name = $_GET['name'];
        $age = $_GET['age'];

        echo '<p>' . $name .'</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $age . '</p>';
    }
?>

<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="age"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

You have done 4 mistakes;

1. methon - should be method
2. You used same name attribute value for input text field and input submit - Use two - do not use same name attribute for more than one field, then value
   will overwrite.
3. concatenation issue - `'<p>' . $name .'</p>'`
4. $GET_ - should be $_GET

Comment: Why this answer received a Downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes in your code.

- You need to change `methon` to `method`
- You need to change `$GET_['name'];` and `$GET_['age'];` `to $_GET['name'];` and `$_GET['age'];`
- Then you are missing a `.` 
  when you wan't to echo your name.

You should do it like this:

HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    Age:<input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
   $name = $_GET['name'];
   $age = $_GET['age'];

   echo '<p>' . $name . '</p>';
   echo '<p>' . $age . '</p>';
?>
```